# Oracle Query to get max of date_column and if null present in that column, then that row should be returned

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I had a situation like to read max(end_time_) when delete_reason_ != 'deleted', but when end_time_ has null, the query should return 2nd row only.

```
SELECT MAX(END_TIME_) FROM TASK_HISTORY WHERE DELETE_REASON_ != 'deleted'
```

is returning me 1st Row. But, my desired result should return 2nd row. As per Oracle documentation, Aggregate functions like max, sum, min shouldn't consider null values unlike Count.

[image]

Is there a way to get the Null value as max if null present, otherwise, max(end_time_) should be my desired output.

Any help will be appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: what if exist more than one row with `end_time_` is null ..? How can we compare and order rows with respect to `end_time_` ?

Comment: When I joined with other table, for each task_def_key, there is a possibility end_time_ might has null.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, here's one option:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> with test (end_time_, delete_reason_) as
  2  (select date '2017-12-13', 'completed' from dual union
  3   select null, null from dual union
  4   select date '2017-12-12', 'deleted' from dual union
  5   select date '2018-01-05', 'unknown' from dual
  6  ),
  7  inter as
  8  (select row_number() over (order  by end_time_ desc) rn,
  9   end_time_, delete_reason_
 10   from test
 11   where nvl(delete_reason_, 'x') <> 'deleted'
 12  )
 13  select end_time_ From inter
 14  where rn = 1;

END_TIME_
----------
NULL

SQL>
SQL> with test (end_time_, delete_reason_) as
  2  (select date '2017-12-13', 'completed' from dual union
  3  -- select null, null from dual union
  4   select date '2017-12-12', 'deleted' from dual union
  5   select date '2018-01-05', 'unknown' from dual
  6  ),
  7  inter as
  8  (select row_number() over (order  by end_time_ desc) rn,
  9   end_time_, delete_reason_
 10   from test
 11   where nvl(delete_reason_, 'x') <> 'deleted'
 12  )
 13  select end_time_ From inter
 14  where rn = 1;

END_TIME_
----------
05.01.2018

SQL>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I just isolated my problem. When I join this table with other tables, this query doesn't fits in that context with had values in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a query something like this to achieve null value as result instead of date when I use max() function.

```
SELECT task_def_key_
     , CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN end_time_ IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 THEN MAX(end_time_) END
FROM TASK_HISTORY WHERE DELETE_REASON_ != 'deleted'
GROUP BY task_def_key_
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from (select * from TASK_HISTORY where DELETE_REASON_ != 'deleted' order by end_time desc) where rownum=1

This will work for your problem